# Disabling Vaadin Errorindicator

Tags: popup, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using validators on several TextFields, which causes to show a popup next to them. As far as I found out, this is realted to the Vaadin errorindicator.

I now want to disable this popup-message, because it creates unhandy behaviour when it comes to using the application on tablets, e.g. an iPad. I already created a separate label showing the error-message and set the errorindicator to hide using CSS as follows:

```
.v-errorindicator { display: none; }
```

The pop up keeps showing anyway. Does anyone know how to disable the popup irrevocable?

Thanks, Hendrik

Comment: I found a dirty workaround that works. Adding the following to the CSS-file disables it. Maybe there is a better way?!

.v-errormessage {
    display: none;
}

Comment: I don't think there is a better way when you want to use the standard validation mechanism of Vaadin. But you could of course not call `addValidator` and do it on your own for each field.

Answer (score 0):

You should cover the validators with try-catch blocks,  in the catch block you can remove the errorstyle with yourTextfield.removeStyleName("v-textfield-error"), also the pop-up won't show.